# Binding a generic list to listview in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wpf-4.0

Lets say I have the following classes. My intention is to bind the List to list view. This is just a sample code. Please help.

```
Class Data
{
public string name {get;set;}
public DateTime date{get;set;}
}

Class Items
{
//Code to get items from database and create a list<Data>...
ListViewDetails.DataContext=List<Data>; //Not Sure if this is the right way...
}
```

XAML:

```
 <ListView Name="ListViewDetails" Margin="4,20,40,100" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource EmployeeTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List}">
    <GridView>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Employee Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=name}"/>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Hire Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=date}"/>
    </GridView>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea found an example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** that is not correct:

1. You don't want to set the data context on a control from code.
2. You don't usually use `List` when binding

Instead:

1. Set the data context for the whole page to a View Model object. You then bind to properties of this object, instead of setting the data context for the control.
2. Use `ObservableCollection<T>` when binding to collections. If the collection has items added or removed, the UI will automatically update to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks the idea really helped..It works..This is a perfect example..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891533/cant-get-wpf-listview-to-bind-to-observablecollection